# How to count number of maximum peak in range Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let say I have value `A = [20 35 50 57 78 90 105 120 143]`, `B=[2 40; 45 80; 85 145];`
`A` is position of maximum peak value and `B` is range.
How to identify a number of maximum peak values in every range?

The answer I want is `[2 3 4]`

Additionally I'd like a cellarray `peak` containing the corresponding peak values:

```
peak = 
      3 x 1 cell:
      [20 35]
      [50 57 78]
      [90 105 120 143]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = [20 35 50 57 78 90 105 120 143];
B = [2 40; 45 80; 85 145];
C = zeros(size(B,1),1); % Initialise C
pks = cell(size(B,1),1); % Initalise peak value collector
for ii = 1:size(B,1)
   pks{ii,1} = A(find(A>B(ii,1) && A<B(ii,2)));
   C(ii,1) = numel(pks{ii,1});
end
C =

     2     3     4
```

Explanation:
The `for` loop crawls through `B` via its rows. For each row it uses the value in column one as a lower threshold and the value in column 2 as a higher threshold. The values in array `A` are checked against this and collected in the cell array `pks`. Finally `numel` returns just the number of elements found this way and stores that in `C`.

I assumed you are defining your ranges as *open* intervals, i.e. the boundaries do not belong to the set. If on the other hand you want *closed* intervals, simple use this:

```
C(ii) = numel(find(A>=B(ii,1) & A<=B(ii,2)));
```

A slightly faster method using logicals instead of `find`, thanks to @rayryeng:

```
C = zeros(size(B,1),1); % Initialise C
for ii = 1:size(B,1)
   tmp = A > B(ii,1) & A < B(ii,2);
   pks{ii,1} = A(tmp);
   C(ii,1) = sum(tmp);
end
```

This works approximately the same as above, albeit faster. The logicals `A > B(ii,1) & A < B(ii,2)` place a `1` on every location within the interval and a `0` on all other locations. Just sum the ones and you've got your desired number. This can be used as logical indexing to get the values of `A`. Open and closed intervals work the same as above.

Comment: Tq very much. I get it ;)

Comment: Easiest way to do this.  I'm writing up a `bsxfun` solution now.

Comment: @rayryeng you and your `bsxfun` always :P I should learn that just to prevent you from stealing my answers ;)

Comment: lol this is the most intuitive way to do it.  I'm just writing an alternative :)

Comment: Unless you are Divakar, then the intuitive way is to `bsxfun` the hell out of everything

Comment: Suggestion.  You don't need to use `find`.  Use `logical` operations and `sum`: `C(ii,1) = sum(A > B(ii,1) & A < B(ii,2));`.

Comment: @danjoro thank you for the accept, but might I suggest accepting either rayryeng's  or divakar's answer? They are both faster and cleaner than my method. Cheers!

Comment: I have one more question. How to put A in the group peak{} by count number of C

Comment: I don't get what you want here. You want a cell array `peak` instead of the array `C`, or do you want the actual peak values of `A` in a cell array? The first solution of mine now contains a cell array `pks` in which the values of `A` are collected per range.

Comment: Yes cell array. the answer i want is peak{}=1x3 where cell 1 contain [20;35], cell 2 contain [50 ;57; 78] and cell 3 contain [ 90; 105; 120; 143].

Comment: That's what `pks` is now. I decided not to call it `peak`, since `peaks` is a build-in function for sure, `peak` might be.

Comment: I don't know whether you understand or not my question.

Comment: I did, `pks` contains the cell *exactly* as you described it, just that it contains a row vector instead of a column vector, but I can just transpose it if you want to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89446/discussion-between-danjoro-and-adriaan).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method is to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).  What we can do is make this into a 3D problem where each slice tells you how many elements are in between each of the corresponding ranges in `B`.  You'd them sum up over every column of each slice:

```
%// Given
A = [20 35 50 57 78 90 105 120 143];
B = [2 40; 45 80; 85 145];

%// Create the 3D matrix we talked about
BL = permute(B(:,1), [2 3 1])
BR = permute(B(:,2), [2 3 1])
out = bsxfun(@ge, A, BL) & bsxfun(@le, A, BR);

%// Reshape output into a vector
vals = reshape(sum(out, 2), 1, []);
```

We get:

```
>> vals

vals =

     2     3     4
```

Comment: Had to steal some part of yours!  Hope that's okay :)

Comment: @Divakar - From the `bsxfun` grandmaster? Absolutely fine with me!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)  and [`nanmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmax.html) -

```
%// Mask of valid binning for A within the bins defined by the columns of B
mask = bsxfun(@ge,A(:),B(:,1).') & bsxfun(@le,A(:),B(:,2).')

%// Create interval version of A
A_intv = bsxfun(@times,mask,A(:))
A_intv(~mask) = nan

%// Get argmax for each bin
[~,max_mask_idx] = nanmax(A_intv,[],1)

%// Get start+1 indices for each bin
[~,start_idx] = max(mask,[],1)

%// Finally the output after subtracting start indices from max_mask_idx
out = max_mask_idx - (start_idx-1)
```

Comment: What happens when the values in `A` are negative? Just use `@min`? And if they are both positive and negative?

Comment: can you simply use `abs(A)` and then `@max`?

Comment: @Adriaan Edited for a generic case.

Comment: I'd say this is faster because you don't have to `permute`.  `nanmax`? Is that a new function?

Comment: @Divakar - Ah, it's part of the Stats toolbox!

Comment: @rayryeng I almost always use `nanmean` etc just to avoid those pesky NaNs in my data